# How to convert C style printf to C++ style cout in eclipse replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to convert C style `LOGD("hello");` to `LOGD<<"hello";`

in eclipse find/replace.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
LOGD\("([^"]*)"\);
```

**Replace:**

```
LOGD << "$1";
```

We capture the text of the string input into `LOGD` in your code, and then use it as the RHS of the `<<` operator in the replacement.  The (first) capture group is made available as `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

While a regexp may be Ok, I recommend to use a macro or better a template inline function rather than a regexp conversion:

```
#define LOGD(x) LOGD_CPP<<(x)
```

or

```
template<typename X> inline void LOGD(const X &x) {LOGD_CPP<<x;}
```

The reason is to be compliant with possible syntax complications inside `x` (nested parentheses, lambda-functions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use in eclipse a regex based find/replace,

if you search by

```
LOG(.*?)\((.*?)\)
```

and replace to

```
LOG\1 << \2
```

this will find all levels in the log like debug, info warning error etc

```
LOGD("DEBUG:hello");
LOGW("WARNING:World"); 
LOGE("ERROR:Fooo"); 
LOGI("INFO:Fooo);
```

and will replace it to

```
LOGD << "DEBUG:hello";
LOGW << "WARNING:World"; 
LOGE << "ERROR:Fooo"; 
LOGI << "INFO:Fooo;
```

---

[image]